# How can I print multiple values on the same line in a Bash for loop?

Tags: bash, variables, awk, grep

I have to output a particular value next to a particular string in a given file. I am able to do that using a combination of grep and awk.

The problem is that I have also to output the file name at the same time as

```
file1= value1
file2= value2
```

and so on. I am not able to print the file name at the same time along with the value.

I have tried with

```bash
for i in $(ls -d */);
do
    cd ${i%%/};
    printf '%s\n' "${i%%/}" >> ../final
    grep -R "Syntax"  ${i%%/}.log | awk '{print $8}'  >> ../final ;
    cd ../
done
```

In this case,the output is coming as

```
file name1
value1
file name2
value2
```

I want them on the same line.

Comment: Missing sample input files examples

Comment: Please take a look at [how to format my code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: What is this `\n` in your code?

Comment: What is the purpose of `-R` in your grep? is `${i%%/}.log` a directory?

Comment: `find */ -name '*.log' -exec awk '/Syntax/{print FILENAME,$8}' {} +` ?

Comment: `find * -type d -prune -exec test -f {}/{}.log \; -exec awk -v d={} '/Syntax/{print d".log=",$8}' {}/{}.log \; >>final`

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  (E.g. [SC2045 - Iterating over ls output is fragile. Use globs.](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2045).)  The report includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

shopt -s nullglob

for dir_ in */; do
    dir=${dir_%/}
    printf '%s=' "$dir"
    awk '/Syntax/{print $8}' "$dir/$dir.log"
done > final
```

- `shopt nullglob` makes globs (e.g. `*/`) expand to nothing when nothing matches (otherwise they expand to the glob pattern itself, which is almost never useful in programs).
- `ls` is designed for interactive use.  There are pitfalls associated with using it in programs (e.g. [Bash Pitfalls #1 (for f in $(ls *.mp3))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)), and it's best avoided.
- There are also pitfalls associated with `cd` (e.g. [Bash Pitfalls #19 (cd /foo; bar)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cd_.2Ffoo.3B_bar)).  It's best, and often easy, to avoid using it.
- `printf` doesn't print a newline by default, so you can put two outputs on a single line by just not using `\n` (newline) with `printf` for the first one.